# Does multiple QMutex needed for every critical section?

Tags: qt, critical-section, thread-synchronization

Should i define one QMutex for all of my critical sections? or i should define one QMutex for each critical sections?

is there any identical concept in  Qt like `lock(object) {...}` in c Sharp?

Answer (score 2):

If you will define one `QMutex` for all of your critical sections then `QMutex::lock()` will lock access to all of your critical sections that use this QMutex object. If you will use many `QMutex` objects then each of them will lock corresponding piece of code.

Say you have:

```
QMutex mutex;

void method1()
{
 mutex.lock();
 //section1
 mutex.unlock();
}

void method2()
{
 mutex.lock();
 //section2
 mutex.unlock();
}
```

Whether thread calls method1() or method2() section1 and section2 are locked. And in the latter case:

```
QMutex mutex1;
QMutex mutex2;

void method1()
{
 mutex1.lock();
 //section1
 mutex1.unlock();
}

void method2()
{
 mutex2.lock();
 //section2
 mutex2.unlock();
}
```

section1 and section2 are locked separately by two different mutexes. So calling method1() won't lock access to section2.

Also note that in most cases it's easier and safer to use `QMutexLocker` than `QMutex` alone.